# Trouble trying to use the MediaHound API

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth

I am trying to build a simple JavaScript app that uses the [MediaHound SDK](https://developer.mediahound.com/docs/core-concepts/getting-started) without transpiling. Here is the error I'm getting:

[image]

```
<oauth>
  <error_description>
    Full authentication is required to access this resource
  </error_description>
  <error>unauthorized</error>
</oauth>
```

I'm following the directions [here](https://developer.mediahound.com/docs/core-concepts/getting-started). I've configured the app on MediaHound's application screen and I've got the Client ID and Client Secret configured properly (when I change them I get a different error).

I'm including the hound.js and my main js file which is this:

```
houndjs.MHSDK.configure('mhclt_Zoetrope', 'My Client Secret is here');

houndjs.MHSearch.fetchResultsForSearchTerm('Gladiator', [houndjs.MHSearch.SCOPE_MOVIE])
  .then(response => {
    const movie = response.content[0].object;
    console.log('First result:', movie.metadata.name);
  });
```

The first line executes fine, it's the search that's throwing an error. Am I making some obvious mistake?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the search is executed right away, before the authentication takes place. This works:

```
houndjs.MHSDK.configure('mhclt_Zoetrope', 'My Client Secret is here').then(() => {

  houndjs.MHSearch.fetchResultsForSearchTerm('Gladiator', [houndjs.MHSearch.SCOPE_MOVIE])
    .then(response => {
      const movie = response.content[0].object;
      console.log('First result:', movie.metadata.name);
    });

});
```